# messaging permission issue for my discord Python bot

Tags: python, bots

```
import discord
import os
intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

#when its ready to run
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
#user interaction commands
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
    await message.channel.send('Hello!')
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

With this code and perms I gave it doesn't work. I heard that i had to enable guildd messages but i tried to give it that with intents. = True but the console said<"its advised to go to developer portal and enable privileged intent", but there is no such intent about" guild messages" and i gave perms for it to send message so im confused about that part.